# ¿Como traer una relacion de uno a muchos usando campos de un inner join?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una tabla llamada **ConfigurationStation** y esta tabla tiene una relacion con la tabla **StaffEdp** , una configuración tiene muchas staffs

la relacion es sencilla ya que los registros de StaffEdp tiene la clave de ConfigurationStation pero resulta que necesita otra condición que me traiga los staffs que tengan una segunda condicion, en **StaffEdp** hay un campo que se llama **turn_strecth_id** pero este campo es de otra tabla, el cual lo traigo en un innerjoin con **ConfigurationStation**, lo necesito traer con with,es decir que cada **ConfigurationStation** tenga su array adentro

```
$query->select('configuration_stretch.name as stretch_name', 'configuration_stretch.id as stretch_id', 'configuration_station.id', 'plant_line.name as line_name', 'configuration_line.description', 'plant_turn.name as turn_name', 'turn_stretch.id as turn_stretch_id', 'configuration_station.name as station_name', 'turn_stretch.edp_name')
        ->join('configuration_stretch', 'configuration_stretch.id', '=', 'configuration_station.configuration_stretch_id')
        ->join('plant_stretch', 'plant_stretch.id', '=', 'configuration_stretch.plant_stretch_id')
        ->join('configuration_line', 'configuration_line.id', '=', 'configuration_stretch.configuration_line_id')
        ->join('plant_line', 'plant_line.id', '=', 'configuration_line.plant_line_id')
        ->join('turn_stretch', 'turn_stretch.configuration_stretch_id', '=', 'configuration_stretch.id')
        ->join('configuration_turn', 'configuration_turn_id', '=', 'turn_stretch.configuration_turn_id')
        ->join('plant_turn', 'plant_turn.id', '=', 'configuration_turn.plant_turn_id')->where('configuration_station.is_critical',true)->where('configuration_line.status_id', $this->STATUS_ACTIVE)->where('plant_stretch.status_id', $this->STATUS_ACTIVE)->groupBy('configuration_stretch.id', 'configuration_station.id', 'plant_line.name', 'configuration_line.description', 'plant_turn.name', 'turn_stretch.id', 'configuration_station.name', 'turn_stretch.edp_name');
```

este es mi inner join usando de principal **ConfigurationStation**

y lo que quiero es trae su relacion con **staff_Edp**

```
 $query->with('staffEdps')
```

asi lo hago y todo bien , pero quiero que en esa relacion no solo me traiga la relacion solo usando el campo **configuration_station_id** sino que tambien me traiga solo los que tengan el campo **turn_stretch_id** que es de una tabla con la que hice join

```
public function staffEdps()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StaffEdp::class, 'configuration_station_id');  
}
```

esta última es la relacion basica de uno a muchos pero necesito filtrar un campo mas en **StaffEdp**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen se puede ver las configuraciones con los staffs pero me trae el **turn_stretch_id** incorrecto porque no se como hacerlo(en la captura por casulidad si nos los correctos)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `with('staffEdps.turnStretch')`, siendo "turnStretch" la relación de "staffEdps" con la foreign key "turn_stretch_id". Con esto traes tanto el modelo de staffEdps y TurnStretch.

Para hacer condicionales en datos de una relación podrías usar `whereHas()` donde el primer parámetro es la relación y segundo un callback.

Por ejemplo:

```
ConfigurationStation::query()->whereHas('staffEdps', function ($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('turn_stretch_id');
});
```

Así mismo puedes intuir que es factible escalar las relaciones. Por ejemplo:

```
ConfigurationStation::query()->whereHas('staffEdps', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('turnStretch', function ($query2) {
        $query2->whereHas('otra_relacion', function($query3) {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```